# Dought appeared in c++ basic datatypes

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long a,b,c;
    char d;
    double e,f;
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f;
    cout<<a<<"\n"<<b<<"\n"<<c<<"\n"<<d<<"\n"<<e<<"\n"<<f;
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
3 444 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493
```

output :

```
3 444 12345678912345 a 334.23 14049.30493
```

Successfully excecuted....
But

Input:

```
211916801 452082285 97592151379235457 p 19856.992 -5279235.721231465
```

output :

is not came perfectly...... so im confused
 some please explain me..why this output happened like this......

give suggesstion to solve this

Comment: *"is not came perfectly"* - What do you get and what did you expect?

Comment: Add `cout.precision(X);` where `X` is the precision you want.

Comment: I need a output exactly as like as input.....

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep in mind that there are many different ways to represent numeric variables, especially floating point numbers. The input/output streams have some default options regarding precision and scientific/fixed formatting.

So, in your case, I guess you expected to get the numbers printed in the exact same format that you entered them. Instead, you probably got the first of your two doubles printed as `19857` and the second as `-5.27924e+06`. So you thought the numbers were not correctly parsed.

The reason that you got these values is that the default [precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision) for floating point numbers is set to 6 and the default [formatting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) made your first number be printed in fixed and your second in scientific notation.

To change the default behavior, you can change these two options, e.g. by invoking a [manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

```
cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << e;
cout << setprecision(10) << fixed << f;
```

Note that you have to `#include <iomanip>` for the additional manipulator `setprecision`. Alternatively you could put `cout.precision(3)` before printing `e` and `cout.precision(10)` before printing `f`.